# WebAPI - Attribute Routing breaks DELETE with WebAPI Cors?

Tags: .net, routes, asp.net-web-api, cors

With the following route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "Set",
           routeTemplate: "api/set/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Set", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
```

mapped to the following method:

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteSet(int id)
    {
     //stuff
    }
```

I can delete sets with this call:

```
   DELETE api/set/1
```

[image]

BUT if I remove the above route in favor of attribute routing:

```
    [HttpDelete("api/set/{id}")]
    [AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteSet(int id)
    {
     //stuff
    }
```

And add to my configuration:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:11089", "*", "*");
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); // new, working with stuff other than delete
        config.EnableCors(cors);  // already working, not new
     }
 }
```

The same request breaks due to a CORS issue:

[image]

In the images you see a query parameter, but this holds true to simple DELETE queries with an id only.  What the heck is going on?  We've invested a lot of time into attribute mapping and it would stink to have to roll everything back because DELETE doesn't work.

Here's another instance of DELETE breaking with a simple id:

[image]

The above came from this request:

```
var options = {
            url: apiEndpoint + 'card/' + id,
            type: 'DELETE',
            dataType: 'json',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        };

        return $.ajax(options)
```

**UPDATE**
If we pepper all of our delete methods with '`[AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]`' then it works.  Seems inelegant and I'd like to leave this open in case anyone has an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be hitting a known issue of using CORS with Attribute Routing. Following issue is currently tracking that.

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/954

This is due to httpmethod constraints that Attribute Routing creates when generating routes.

**Workarounds** (You have couple of options here):

- Explicitly decorate the action with HttpOptions verb attribute too so that this constraint also gets added and your OPTIONS request can pass through.
- Create a custom route builder which adds OPTIONS to all routes (you can modify this behavior if your like though). Some sample code:

  ```
  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new CustomRouteBuilder());

  public class CustomRouteBuilder : HttpRouteBuilder
  {
      public override IHttpRoute BuildHttpRoute(HttpRouteValueDictionary defaults, HttpRouteValueDictionary constraints, 
                                                  string routeTemplate)
      {
          HttpMethodConstraint currentMethodConstraint = (HttpMethodConstraint)constraints["httpMethod"];
          List<HttpMethod> methods = currentMethodConstraint.AllowedMethods.ToList();
          if (!methods.Contains(HttpMethod.Options))
          {
              methods.Add(HttpMethod.Options);
          }

          HttpMethodConstraint newMethodConstraint = new HttpMethodConstraint(methods.ToArray());
          HttpRouteValueDictionary newConstraints = new HttpRouteValueDictionary();
          newConstraints["httpMethod"] = newMethodConstraint;
          return base.BuildHttpRoute(defaults, newConstraints, routeTemplate);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Wow!  I *just* found out that this worked from trial and error.  Nice to have confirmation - you're saving my butt today

Comment: I updated the post above to add one more workaround.Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: HttpRouteBuilder has been removed from web api 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529522/httproutebuilder-where-did-it-go-and-why